# Java collisions are not working for 2D game

Tags: java, collision

**Introduction**

I have made a thread in the past regarding this problem and after a spending a long time modifying my code with the help of other users on this forum I am still at the same place as where I had started so I am taking a different approach.

**What I want to do**

I am not going to ask you to make my game for me so instead of posting all of my code for my game I have made a very similar and very simple version of the game which only has two class's the main and the game class. What the simple code I am providing dose: there are two rectangles and one of the moves with the keyboard input, and thats it, no background, no images, no animations and very little code.

**My problem / my question**

The problem I am having in my game is the collisions, in this example the two rectangles, I need to add some code to my game that will stop the one rectangle intersecting the other, I have looked at many tutorials, many guides regarding this problem but have made no progress and am hoping the users of this forum will help me solve this problem.

**The Code**

As I mentioned above, there is very little code for this game only 2 class's and nothing else required so if you need to you can simply create 2 class's (Game and Play) and run this game on your computer. Note you will need to set up slick with your compiler before you use this code.

The main class (Game)

```
package javagame;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Game extends StateBasedGame{

    public static final String gamename = "Ham Blaster! 2.0";

    public static final int play = 1;

    public Game(String gamename){//create window on statup
        super(gamename);//adds title to screen
        this.addState(new Play(play));
    }

    public void initStatesList(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException{

        this.getState(play).init(gc, this);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppGameContainer appgc;//the window for your game
        try{
            appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Game(gamename));
            appgc.setDisplayMode(640, 360,false);
            appgc.start();
        }catch(SlickException e){
        e.printStackTrace();}
    }}
```

The Play Class

```
    package javagame;

import java.awt.Rectangle;

import org.newdawn.slick.Animation;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Play extends BasicGameState{

    Animation bucky, movingUp, movingDown, movingLeft, movingRight;
    Image worldMap;
    boolean quit = false;//gives user to quit the game
    int[] duration = {200, 200};//how long frame stays up for
    int buckyPositionX = 0;
    int buckyPositionY = 0;
    int shiftX = buckyPositionX + 320;//keeps user in the middle of the screem
    int shiftY = buckyPositionY + 160;//the numbers are half of the screen size

    Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(shiftX, shiftY,90,90);
    Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(500 + buckyPositionX, 330 + buckyPositionY, 210, 150);

    public Play(int state){
    }   
    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{
    }


    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{


    g.fillRect(shiftX, shiftY,90,90);
    g.fillRect(500 + buckyPositionX, 330 + buckyPositionY, 210, 150);
    }


    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)throws SlickException{
    Input input = gc.getInput();

    //up
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){buckyPositionY += 2;}

    //down
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){buckyPositionY -= 2;}
    //left
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){buckyPositionX += 2;}
    //right
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){buckyPositionX -= 2;}
}   


    public int getID(){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

If you require any additional information please tell me and I will reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Perhaps you need to update the rectangles on your keys update and then call http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects(java.awt.Rectangle) to determine if they will be collided.

Comment: Where are you checking for collisions?  I don't think it's automatic; you need to use a method like [**`intersects`**](http://slick2d.org/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/geom/Rectangle.html#intersects(org.newdawn.slick.geom.Shape)).

Comment: I suggest you get rid of X+Y position variables and just use `Rectangle`, since it has X+Y coordinates (and then you can use [intersects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects(java.awt.Rectangle))). General coding tip - Have `width` and `height` variables, and say `width/2` instead of `320`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with the framework, but I understand that the primitive types provide an intersects() method to determine if two objects collide with each other. You need to call it manually or find some component were you can register your objects so it does it for you.